# 2 columns to stay in one line when displaying in cel with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I m new to bootstrap,

I have 2 text elements that share the same line.

Thing is in mobile, the UNDO link goes in another line, when there still is some available space...

How can I do it?

Here is my code?

```
<a href='#' class='undo_link'><i class='icon  icon-cross3 noty_close' ></i></a>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-8'> Success </div>
    <div class='col-lg-3' align='right'><a class='undo' href='/restore'><span class='undo_link'>UNDO</span> </a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with col-lg-8 and col-lg-3. Try replace that with
col-sm-8 and col-sm-3. You should read how grid system works in bootstrap and understand how xs, sm, md, lg modifiers work: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

Comment: OK - I'm glad it helped. Can you mark this as the answer?